# I'm trying to get the process notepad by name but getting exception IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms

Getting exception IndexOutOfRangeException
How can i solve it ?
What cause it ?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
      int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
   }
}
```

Why do I get this exception ?

Index was outside the bounds of the array

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233080
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=Read
  StackTrace:
       at Read
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `GetProcessesByName` isn't returning any results; there is no object at index `0`. This means that it's not finding the process `notepad`.

Comment: I am deleting my answer since yours is the better one, +1 :)

Comment: LOL you right i forgot to open notepad. Sorry.